# In Meteor, how to update one db field when another field changes?

Tags: meteor

General question: in Meteor, what's the best way to implement business logic that triggers whenever a model is updated -- e.g., for updating dependent fields or validations or...

Specific example: I'd like to add a "slug" field to Lists collection in the [Meteor todos example](http://www.meteor.com/examples/todos). The slug needs to automatically update whenever a list's name is changed.

Here's what I've got... I'm observing *every* change to a list to see if its slug needs to be created/updated. This is in a *shared* models.js (runs server and client-side, to get the benefits of latency compensation):

```js
// Lists -- {name: String}
Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");

var listsObserver = Lists.find().observe({
    added: updateSlug,
    changed: updateSlug
});

function updateSlug(doc, idx) {
    var slug = (doc.name || '').replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    if (slug !== doc.slug) {
        console.log("Updating slug for '" + doc.name + "' to " + slug);
        Lists.update(doc._id, {$set: {slug: slug}});
    }
}
```

(And as in the original todos example, server/publish.js publishes all of `Lists.find()` as "lists", and client/todos.js subscribes to that collection.)

The code above seems to work, but somehow doesn't look quite right to me. Questions:

1. Is observing the Lists collection like this a reasonable approach? It seems like
   it could be inefficient -- *any* change to a Lists document will trigger this code.
2. Should I be doing a different (simulated) update client-side, or is it OK to let
   this same Mongo/Minimongo update run on both?
3. Do I need to call `listsObserver.stop()` at some point to dispose the observer?
   And if so, when?

(I'm just getting started with Meteor, so perhaps my biases from other environments are leaking through. The implied meta-question here is, am I even thinking about this problem in the right way?)

Comment: Hmm... just found [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463730/647002) in an older question about Meteor data validation. It seems to say you should implement RPC-style Meteor.methods for model editing, and then block the automatic sync of the client's minimongo models back to the server. (Hoping that's not still the recommendation. That automatic, realtime, two-way sync is one of the big attractions of Meteor.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest using the Collection-Hooks package. It extends the collection operations with before and after hooks. This is better than having a lot of collection Observes or ObserveChanges, especially on the server where the overhead for collection observes can get very large.

This works on both the client and the server. If you implement it on the client you will get the benefit of updating the local collection (latency compensation) and the change will be pushed to the server so no need to do it again.

You also get the benefit of only doing one MongoDB operation instead of two or more like you would with observes or observeChanges.

You might use it like so:

```
var beforeInsertSlug = function(userId, doc) {
    var slug = (doc.name || '').replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    if (slug !== doc.slug) {
        console.log("Updating slug for '" + doc.name + "' to " + slug);
        doc.slug = slug;
    }
};

var beforeUpdateSlug = function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options){
    if(modifier && modifier.$set && modifier.$set.doc && _.isString(modifier.$set.doc.name)){
        var slug = (modifier.$set.doc.name || '').replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        if (slug !== doc.slug) {
            console.log("Updating slug for '" + modifier.$set.doc.name + "' to " + slug);
            modifier.$set.doc.slug = slug;
        }
    }

};

Lists.before.insert(beforeInsertSlug);

Lists.before.update(beforeUpdateSlug);
```

You can find the package here: https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks

Comment: Wow I didn't even know this existed!

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to find in the Meteor core.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing in server code. Basically put this code in Meteor.methods(), along with any other checks and updates you want making to the Lists Collection.

Although the code below looks a bit messy, and certainly hard to understand with the line starting with var slug:

```
Meteor.methods({
   myupdate: function (doc) {

     var slug = (doc.name || '').replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

     if (slug !== doc.slug) {
        console.log("Updating slug for '" + doc.name + "' to " + slug);
        Lists.update(doc._id, {$set: {slug: slug}});
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: How does Meteor know to run `myupdate` every time anyone tries to modify a list's name? Or does every programmer who might modify a list's name just have to know to _also_ call `myupdate` afterwards? (I'm looking for something that can run automatically, and be bulletproof.)

Comment: Under what situations would you modify a lists name? i.e. To write the change to the database? If that's the case just combine the above code to your main write. If not let me know, the solution may be putting the code in a Publish() using observeChanges().

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this is to define a custom template function and trigger it in the template that is changing.  For example:

In client.js

```
Template.myTemplate.custom_function_to_update = function() {
    // do my update code.  i.e. MyCollections.Update(...);
}
```

In the html file with the template

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <!-- Normal template code -->
    {{ custom_function_to_update }}
</template>
```

and every time the template "myTemplate" updates, it will call your method.

Comment: But template code only runs client-side, and only for that specific template, right? So it would be very easy for a change to slip into the model without triggering the business logic. Using the todo example, if only that template is responsible for keeping the list.slug up to date, then any other code that modifies list.title would leave an out-of-sync slug.

Comment: This will also run your update once for every client who has that template open, not ideal.